# Ubuntu 18.04 Doesn't actually change the language for input

Tags: keyboard, 18.04, language-support, arabic

I am trying to type in Arabic as well as in English. I set up the Arabic keyboard using the following steps:

Settings -> Region & Language -> + -> Arabic

I also added Arabic (QWERTY) just to check.

After doing that I get the little switcher on the top right. The problem is when I switch the language it keeps typing in English. Anyone know what is going on? I am very confused!

Comment: Restarting magically worked. Still a bug though!

Comment: In my case, it didn't work even after restarting. the language icon is there but still types in English. Anyone solved it?

Answer (score 47):

It is probably a bug from GNOME, I don't know, but restarting GNOME works. (You won't lose your open apps or the arrangement in virtual desktops.)

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then write `r` and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: works perfectly, شكرا, but what the `r` command means

Comment: @BasheerAL-MOMANI I guess it is r for restart

Comment: @JorgeeFG I did restart ubuntu but didn't work. restarting GNOME as you mentioned worked like a charm!

Comment: @BasheerAL-MOMANI It will force write changes.

Comment: I'm doing this on every boot. Is there a more permanent solution?

Comment: @Arkanoid if you use multiple languages, I don't know, until they fix the problem. If you're using just one, take a look at language settings and remove unnecessary ones

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue in pop_os 20.10. This is definitely NOT related to gnome desktop. At least that's what the Gnome devs told me.

Comment: From time to time (~2 times a week) my language switcher also stops working (Ubuntu 20.04, 20.10). Previously I had to restart the system but now I have a quicker solution thanks to this answer. I hope this annoying bug will be fixed some day.

Answer (score 7):

you should restart
I had the same exact problem and after a restart, it worked

Comment: nice, had the same exact issue, didn't knew from where the problem was, restarted and it got solved :D thanks!